# Как найти класс определённого элемента в jQuery и простроить логику кода?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

нужна помощь. Есть три div с разными id:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="gift10">
    <img class="gift-block-image black-gift">
    <h2>Тайный подарок #1</h2>

<ul id="gift-colors">
        <li class="black checked"></li>
        <li class="red"></li>
        <li class="blue"></li>
        <li class="yellow"></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="price">1000<span class="rouble">i</span></span>
    <button type="submit">Выбрать!</button>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе цвета (клике на ul#gift-colors > li) этому li присваивался класс "checked" и менялась картинка (через присвоение классу "gift-block-image" еще одного класса, к примеру, "red-gift" вместо "black-gift").

Картинка уникальна для каждого цвета каждого товара. Проблема в том, что не могу правильно прописать селекторы: изменения происходят у всех div сразу, а не у определённого. Как сделать так, чтобы функция работала с определенным div? Или может у моего кода вообще неправильная логика и это можно реализовать проще (новичок в jQuery)?

Пока что получилось сделать только присваивание "checked" определённому div:

```
$(function() {
    $("#gift10 ul li").click(function() {
        $("#gift10 ul li").removeClass("checked");         
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="gift" id="gift...">

$(function() {
    $(".gift ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("checked");         
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");

        $(this).closest(".gift").find(".gift-block-image")....;         
    })
});
```