# Добавить название класса к другому классу (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, классы, css-selectors

Всем привет, нужна помощь. 
Есть код:

```
<div id="gift10">
    <img class="gift-block-image black">
    <h2>Тайный подарок #1</h2>

<ul id="gift-colors">
        <li class="black checked"></li>
        <li class="red"></li>
        <li class="blue"></li>
        <li class="yellow"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".gift ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("checked");         
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");
        $(this).closest(".gift").find(".gift-block-image").addClass('red');         
    })
});
```

Сейчас по клику на li к классу "gift-block-image" добавляется еще один класс "red". Подскажите, каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы вместо "red" добавлялось название класса ("blue", "yellow"...), на который кликнули?

Comment: Думаю ваш вопрос можно просто закрыть т.к  такое ощущение что вы нарочно спутали код и хотите чтобы кто то решал ребус.... Можете показать у вас в коде что то с класом .gift ? или надо предположить что это .gift10 ?

Comment: @Arsen Код в вопросе - смесь из верстки автора и скрипта из моего ответа на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855839

Comment: @Igor может это просто дубликат?

Comment: @Arsen Не, это автор потихонечку делает свое задание из кусков :).

Comment: @Igor, я так и понял )) + от меня наставнику ))

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="gift" id="gift...">
  ...
  <ul id="gift-colors">
    <li data-color="black" class="black checked"></li>
    <li data-color="red" class="red"></li>
    <li data-color="blue" class="blue"></li>
    <li data-color="yellow" class="yellow"></li>
  </ul>

$(function() {
    $(".gift ul li").click(function() {
        var $img = $(this).closest(".gift").find(".gift-block-image");
        var oldColor = $(this).closest("ul").find("li.checked").data("color");         
        $img.removeClass(oldColor);
        $img.addClass($(this).data("color"));         

        $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("checked");         
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");
    })
});
```

Comment: А вы пробовали свой код в работе ?

Comment: @Arsen Нет конечно. Код отличный, доверьтесь мне.

Comment: код супер )) просто на взгляд запускаю код... не будет работать )) хотя по всей вероятности вина Dmitry ))

Comment: @Arsen А-а-а, это я невнимательно посмотрел на вопрос, посчитав, что автор учел ответ на его предыдущий вопрос.